# getMemberGroups call fails with insufficient privileges

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get user's group memberships (transitive) and using Microsoft Graph for it. I used to use group claims in token but after switching to the AD v2.0 endpoint (for dynamic consent support etc.), the token doesn't contain those so they need to be retrieved from AD separately.

The [`user/getMemberGroups`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_getmembergroups) operation does exactly that but I have a hard time getting it to work *without granting* `Directory.Read.All` permissions. The documentation says that any of these should work:

- `User.Read` and `Group.Read.All`
- `User.ReadBasic.All` and `Group.Read.All`
- `Directory.Read.All`
- `Directory.ReadWrite.All`
- `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`

Yet with an on-behalf-of access token for user to Microsoft Graph, the request always fails with response `403 Forbidden` and error code `Authorization_RequestDenied`

**Http request**

```http
POST /v1.0/me/getMemberGroups HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer <removed>
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: dbb2ead3-9863-57ef-af09-d45c3ab88e69

{
  "securityEnabledOnly": false
}
```

I'm actually using the .NET SDK to perform the operation but can repro it with pure HTTP request, which is more clear.

Looking inside the access token, this has both `Group.Read.All` and `User.Read.All` which should be a sufficient combination.

```json
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",  
  [....]
  "scp": "Group.Read.All User.Read User.Read.All"
}
```

Current user is a Global Admin for the AD tenant in question so I suppose this shouldn't be a question of him having less privileges to the AD items either. I have done the admin consent for this application using v2.0 endpoints  (not that it should matter when using this admin user, AFAIK)

Comment: I don't believe this should matter, but _just in case_, does using `/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/getMemberGroups` work? Just confirming since the documentation doesn't list `/me`.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur nope, tried that also. Also, the `/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups` endpoint works fine with `Directory.Read.All` permissions. The alias is not documented at the page for that operation but it's mentioned in [top-level documentation for Users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [getMemberGroups](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryobject_getmembergroups) function should only require both `Group.Read.All` and in your case (for `../me/getMemberGroups`) `User.Read`.  However, due to a bug in the authorization check, this currently requires `Directory.Read.All` (which is what you've observed).  I'm afraid I don't have an ETA for this fix, but will report back when I hear more.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea if it'll take weeks or months? In the meantime I think it would be good if there would be some other kind of note about this than this question on SO. For example a Github issue would be perfect but a comment on the docs would be useful too, if the fix takes a while. In any case I'll mark this as an answer as the question itself is solved.

Comment: We experienced the same issue with the [checkMemberGroups](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_checkmembergroups) function.

Comment: Yes - same issue applies there.  We can update the docs until the fix is in

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT I hope the bug is fixed ? If so could you please update your answer ?

Comment: is this bug fixed?

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue, can you provide an update?